# Twincat : variable := null

Tags: twincat

I am working on a SCL project in TwinCAT and I am having trouble with initializing a LREAL variable. I have tried using the "null" value to represent an uninitialized state, but the variable always ends up being initialized to 0. I have also tried using the "UNINITIALIZED" or "INITIAL_VALUE" identifiers, but they don't seem to work. I need help finding a way to properly represent an uninitialized LREAL variable in TwinCAT.

I have tried using the "null" value to represent an uninitialized state, but the variable always ends up being initialized to 0. I have also tried using the "UNINITIALIZED" or "INITIAL_VALUE" identifiers, but they don't seem to work.I need help finding a way to properly represent an uninitialized LREAL variable in TwinCAT.

Comment: Please provide some examples or code.

Comment: STRUCT
 KnotVector : ARRAY [1..5] OF LREAL;
END_STRUCT

When I convert the structure to string, the result is : "KnotVector":[1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]

But here, I want just : "KnotVector":[1.0]

So I want remplace 0 with null, because I want the the smallest possible string.

Comment: Maybe it's a solution for you to write your own custom function. That way you could read the array and build the output string until you encounter a 0.0 value and ignore the rest of the array from there... Do keep in mind that you might have to deal with the [1.0,0.0,1.5,0.0,0.0] case in your code/logic. That depends on the application I guess...

Answer (score 3):

LREAL is a primitive type and therefore cannot be nulled. Every combination of bits represents actual number - with few exceptions for NaN, +Infinity and -Infinity

What you can do is create a pointer to LREAL. Pointer of value 0 is null - it's not pointing to anything. Then, in implementation part, you can assign an address to your pointer using __NEW

Declaration:

```
myPointer : POINTER TO LREAL;
myBool : BOOL;
```

Implementation:

```
// pointer still 0
IF myBool THEN
  myBool := FALSE;
  myPointer := __NEW(LREAL, 1);
  // pointer is now assigned an address, therefore not 0
END_IF
```

Comment: It's great that you mentioned primitive type, I think it's the core concept to understand this problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is no null in TwinCAT I think. Once you define a variable, it gets set to the default value. In case of an LREAL that is 0.0.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your clarification in the comment section of your question, I think you need to write your own custom function. That way you could read the array and build the output string until you encounter a 0.0 value and ignore the rest of the array from there...
Do keep in mind that you might have to deal with

- the [1.0,0.0,1.5,0.0,0.0] case (maybe not every 0.0 value has the meaning of "skip all other values of the array", it might be valid data). And what about [1.0, **0.0, 0.0**, 0.0, 0.0] where the first three values are valid data, but the last two are not?
- allowing a variable-size array as input (using a pointer + length variable instead of a complete array as input).

Dealing with these cases should happen in your own code/logic for the function and depends of the application.

Answer (score 0):

There's even another option: wrapping the type.

Say you define a struct that is the combination of a value and a BOOL called "valid" like this:

```
TYPE ST_VectorElement:
STRUCT
    Value  : LREAL;
    bValid : BOOL;
END_STRUCT
END_TYPE
```

That way you can loop over the array of VectorElements that is called KnotVector and check every element of the array to see if it is valid/useful and use the value accordingly.